# Workflow: Assign task to Account team in hierarchical fashion?

Tags: workflow, tasks, account-teams

I've set up account teams for all of my accounts.

I have also set up a workflow rule to create a task when a check box is updated at the account level.

The task is created and assigned to the project manager on the account team.

The issue is that I have multiple project managers for some accounts, and would like to start from the bottom and work to the top when assigning the task.

My team roles are PM 1, PM 2, PM 3, etc.

Is there a wildcard character or something I can use to facilitate this?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a way to do this with a trigger in a fairly straightforward manner.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: Thank you for the response Ray. We did end up using a trigger. I recall there was a specific reason that we wanted to avoid a coded solution, but I cannot remember what that was.